# Mix SQL Rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT package_stats.developer 
      ,xf_user.username 
      ,xf_user.email 
      ,xf_user_profile.homepage 
      ,xf_user_profile.location 
      ,xf_user_profile.about 
      ,CASE WHEN field_id ='Github' THEN field_value ELSE '' END AS Github
      ,CASE WHEN field_id ='Repository' THEN field_value ELSE ''  END AS Repository
      ,CASE WHEN field_id ='twitter' THEN field_value ELSE '' END AS Twitter

FROM package_stats, xf_user, xf_user_field_value, xf_user_profile 
WHERE xf_user.username = package_stats.developer AND  xf_user_profile.user_id = xf_user.user_id AND xf_user_field_value.user_id = xf_user.user_id AND xf_user_field_value.field_value <> ''
```

Which outputs the following:

```
developer   username    email      about     Github              Repository           Twitter 
John Doe      jdoe    j@doe.com   It's me   https://github....       
John Doe      jdoe    j@doe.com   It's me      
John Doe      jdoe    j@doe.com   It's me                       https://link....   
John Doe      jdoe    j@doe.com   It's me                                            https://twitter.com/...
```

How can I mix all those rows into a single row?

Comment: that looks like what?

Comment: Heya! Seems like your query is not matching with the output you're giving. I am missing the `homepage` and `location` columns output, for example. Could you make them match?

Comment: Also: this `xf_user.username = package_stats.developer` join will never work when they would contain `John Doe` and `jdoe` respectively. So I'm guessing this is not the real query or not the real (or "real-like") data :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ps.developer, u.username, u.email, 
       up.homepage, up.location, up.about,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ufv.field_id = 'Github' THEN ufv.field_value END) AS Github,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ufv.field_id = 'Repository' THEN ufv.field_value END) AS Repository,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ufv.field_id = 'twitter' THEN ufv.field_value END) AS Twitter   
FROM package_stats ps JOIN
     xf_user u
     ON u.username = ps.developer JOIN
     xf_user_profile up
     ON up.user_id = u.user_id JOIN
     xf_user_field_value ufv
     ON ufv.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE ufv.field_value <> '' 
GROUP BY ps.developer, u.username, u.email, 
         up.homepage, up.location, up.about;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- All columns should be qualified with a table alias, to avoid ambiguity.
- There is no reason to have an `ELSE` clause for this purpose.  If there are no matches, then the column is `NULL` (a reasonable value).
- If there could be more than one field for a given category, use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a (fake) aggregation function and group by

```
SELECT package_stats.developer 
      ,xf_user.username 
      ,xf_user.email 
      ,xf_user_profile.homepage 
      ,xf_user_profile.location 
      ,xf_user_profile.about 
      ,min(CASE WHEN field_id ='Github' THEN field_value END) AS Github
      ,min(CASE WHEN field_id ='Repository' THEN field_value   END) AS Repository
      ,min(CASE WHEN field_id ='twitter' THEN field_value END ) AS Twitter

    FROM package_stats
    INNER JOIN  xf_user ON xf_user.username = package_stats.developer
    INNER JOIN  xf_user_profile  ON xf_user_profile.user_id = xf_user.user_id 
    INNER JOIN  xf_user_field_value v1 ON xf_user_field_value.user_id = xf_user.user_id 
    WHERE xf_user_field_value.field_value <> '' 
    GROUP BY package_stats.developer 
      ,xf_user.username 
      ,xf_user.email 
      ,xf_user_profile.homepage 
      ,xf_user_profile.location 
      ,xf_user_profile.about
```

and don't use implict joins  are not clear ..
the implict join is an arcaic  sintax

Comment: This will work with `MAX` as aggregation function, but not with `MIN` - except when you remove the `ELSE ''` from the `CASE` statements. I'm not sure why...